# express js render without replacing html tags (like <p>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, render

I'm working on blog-like project and I need to render text without replacing html tags.

./app.js

```
//app.js
...
var text = 'Hello <b>World</b>'
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('index', {
        text: text
    });
});
...
```

./views/index.jade

```
//-index.jade
p= text
```

When I render this:

Here is what I'm getting:

```
Hello &lt;b&gt;World&lt;/b&gt;
```

Here is what I'm looking for

```
Hello <b>World</b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for your Jade file: `p= !{text}`. This should avoid your content being escaped.